# I need help with understanding this proof that the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the same as that induced by the square metric

Tags: general-topology

Here's the proof:[image]

I'm basically struggling with following the logic used in the proof. How is for each $i$ there an $\epsilon_i$ such that $(x_i - \epsilon_i, x_i + \epsilon_i)$ is contained in $(a_i, b_i)$? Why do we choose $\epsilon$ minimun? And how does that imply $B_{\rho}(x, \epsilon)$ is contained in $B$?

I'm sorry if this is too many questions. Thanks for your help.

Forgot to add that the square metric is $\rho(x, y) = \text{max}_i \{|x_i - y_i|\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$(a_i,b_i)$ is an open set containing $x_i$, so there must be a smaller open set containing $x_i$ which is contained in $(a_i,b_i)$. (Definition of open set)

$(x_i - \epsilon_i, x_i + \epsilon_i)$ is contained in $(a_i,b_i)$. But we don't know whether $(x_j - \epsilon_j, x_j + \epsilon_j)$ is contained in $(a_j,b_j)$ for $j \neq i$.

So we need to choose the minimum $\epsilon$ in order to make sure that $(x_j - \epsilon_j, x_j + \epsilon_j)$ is contained in $(a_j,b_j)$ for all $j$.